# What is the apache2ctl "-k" flag?

Tags: apache-http-server

I've been searching for an hour and have found a hundred examples that use it, but no explanation of what it does. I did check `man apache2ctl`; it doesn't explain the k flag either (elthough it does use it in examples).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, it's a little buried [in the description](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html):

> When acting in pass-through mode, `apachectl` can take all the arguments available for the `httpd` binary.
>
> ```
> apachectl [ httpd-argument ]
> ```

So let's look at [`http`'s documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) then:

> ```
> -k start|restart|graceful|stop|graceful-stop
> ```
>
> Signals `httpd` to start, restart, or stop.

So if you use `-k <option>`, you'll simply pass on to `httpd`, which needs this argument.

If you don't use the `-k`, `apache2ctl` will instead look for commands that it will handle itself, which are again the same as `httpd` would take.

---

Looking at the source code exhibits this behavior, where a `case` statement checks whether the first argument is one of the recognized internal commands, and finally (as a fallback), everything's passed onto `httpd`.

```bsh
case $ARGV in
start)
  HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} -k $ARGV # <= note the -k here
  # ...
stop|graceful-stop)
  # ...
# ...
*)
    $HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} $ARGV
    ERROR=$?
esac
```

Comment: I'm new to this. Could you explain to me in plain English what ommitting the k flag will actually do? On my Ubuntu server it seems to make no difference if I use the k flag or not, it always restarts successfully as far as I can tell.

Comment: What you're seeing is normal. Like I said, if you do not use `-k`, then `apachectl` will handle the commands itself, but it does the same as `httpd`. If you use `-k`, the command is passed on to `httpd` as-is.

Comment: I still don't really know what that means in terms of functionality, to be honest, but are you saying then that it doesn't matter if you use the -k flag or not, it will do the same thing in a roundabout way?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, yeah. It's for historical reasons that both work.

Comment: "little buried"?  Why not to call this - the apache documentation really sucks.
I do not think this is for historical reasons, is for reasons of passing also other arguments to httpd.

Answer (score 2):

Edit to add: Sorry, slhck types faster than me :D

'apache2ctl' is actually just a front-end for the 'httpd' executable and runs in two modes depending on if you're wanting it to be SysV init scriptable or if you're wanting to pass-through options to the httpd executable. The -k actually gets passed through to httpd.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html

> When acting in pass-through mode, apachectl can take all the arguments
>   available for the httpd binary.
>
> apachectl [ httpd-argument ]

So from the httpd man page, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html

> -k start|restart|graceful|stop|graceful-stop Signals httpd to start, restart, or stop.